# What link is this?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Please consider the following link

[image]

its corresponding Jones polynomial is

[image]

Could you please identify such link as a member of the Thistlethwaite Link Table?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SnapPy, recommended by N. Owad ([Are isomorphic the following two links?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251381/are-isomorphic-the-following-two-links)) and Jim Belk ([What knot is this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113877/what-knot-is-this/2113939#2113939)); I am obtaining the following result.

The link is drawing inside the SnapPy environment as

[image]

Now using the commands

```
N= Manifold()
N.identify()
```

we obtain the output

```
[7^2_6(0,0)(0,0), L7a1(0,0)(0,0)]
```

It is to say the link L7a1 in the Thistlethwaite Link Table.

The Jones polynomial for L7a1 computed using the Mathematica package KnotTheory is

[image]

The ratio between the Jones polynomial of the original link and the Jones polynomial  of L7a1 is the monomial $q^{-3}$.

Such ratio confirms that the original link is L7a1.  Do you agree?

Comment: That appears to have a different Jones polynomial then you suggested, so you might want to recheck your computation.

Comment: @PVAL-inactive, thanks for your comment.  As yo can see in the answer the two Jones polynomials only are different  by a multiplicative monomial-

Comment: @PVAL-inactive For links, the Jones polynomial depends on the orientation. Changing the orientation of one component of the link, but not the other, can multiple the Jones polynomial by a power of $q$.

Answer (score 0):

See here http://www.indiana.edu/~linkinfo/results.php?searchmode=0&category%5B%5D=%3C%3D6&category%5B%5D=%3D7&category%5B%5D=%3D8&category%5B%5D=%3D9&category%5B%5D=%3D%2710%27&category%5B%5D=%3D%2711%27&name=%3D1&jones_polynomial=%3D1&startrow=0&rows=4188

for a list of all links up to 11 crossings with their corresponding Jones' polynomial and here http://www.indiana.edu/~linkinfo/descriptions/jones_homfly_kauffman_description/polynomial_defn.html to see the conventions used in determining the actual polynomial (which I am pretty sure are different then your conventions). Linkinfo and knotinfo make pretty short work of these types of questions.